# CakePHP cache i18n translate

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, internationalization

When I forget to translate something, somewhere Project VIEW, I change the file **/app/Locale/por/LC_MESSAGES/default.po** and sending it back to the server.

But mostly, this *'new translation'*, takes HOURS to be viewed, in short: I just send the file, cleaned the cache and browser CakePHP, press F5, and ... **NOTHING HAPPENS**.

For what reason?

**[EDIT]**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.0.description', array('label' => false, 
'class' => 'span12', 'div' => array('class' => 'span7'), 'rows' => 3,
'placeholder' => __('Type the description'))); ?>
```

Comment: All cache (app/tmp/) and browser cache.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To force the language to update you can clear the `persistent` and `models` directories in the `/tmp/cache` directory. If view caching is enabled you'll have to clean out `views` as well.

Caching is disabled when `debug` is set to `2` (which is the value for using the framework during development) and the `persistent` directory is populated with new cache files, overwriting the old ones each time a view is loaded. So the `debug` switch and subsequent browser refresh might clean the old language files for you.

Comment: Thanks my friend. Its exactly that!

Comment: on linux this command might be handy (to be run from application directory) `find app/tmp/cache -type f -delete` - it will delete all files from cache

Answer (score 2):

I found a strange solution:

I set (app/Config/core.php)...

```
Configure::write('debug', 2); // It was 0
```

Press, F5... wait... and works.
Later, I back...

```
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

Press F5 again, and works.

Why? I no have idea.

Comment: Because turning on debug changes the default cache duration from [~forever to 10 seconds](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/core.php#L354-L358).

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you1

Answer (score 0):

Even if `Configure::write('debug', 2);` I recommend to delete the remote folder containing the translations, refresh with browser (to state that nothing is translated anymore) then reupload the translations folder.

Works perfectly that way for me.